# My register.php doesn't add username to my database

Tags: php

```
<?php
define('PASSWORD_ENCRYPTION', "bcrypt");
define('PASSWORD_SHA512_ITERATIONS', 25000);
define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT_COST', "13");
define('PASSWORD_SALT', "/8Wncr26eAmxD1l6cAF9F8");

function hashPassword($password)
{
    $salt = "$2b$" . PASSWORD_BCRYPT_COST . "$" . PASSWORD_SALT;

    if(PASSWORD_ENCRYPTION == "bcrypt")
    {
        $newPassword = crypt($password, $salt);

    }
    else {
        $newPassword = $password;
        for ($i=0; $i<PASSWORD_SHA512_ITERATIONS; $i++) {
            $newPassword = hash('sha512', $salt.$newPassword.$salt);
        }
    }
        return $newPassword;

}

$msg ="";

// You have to change SERVER username password and database to your stuff

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','dwellers');

    $name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $cPassword = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['cPassword']);
    $active = 1;
    if($password != $cPassword)
    {
        $msg = "Password not the same";
    }else{
        $hash = hashPassword($password);
        $con->query("INSERT INTO user(username,password,email,active) VALUES('$name','$hash','$email','$active')");
        $msg = "your Registration was successful";
    }

}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MMORPG Registration File</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>MMORPG Account registration</h1>

<?php if($msg !="") echo $msg . "<br><br>"; ?>

<form method="POST" action="register.php">
    <label>Username:</label><input name="username"><br>
    <label>Email:</label><input name="email"><br>
    <label>Password:</label><input name="password" type="password"><br>
   <label>Confirm Password:</label><input name="cPassword" type="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm using XAMPP, and this code doesn't add username, email and password to the database. It worked the first time, but when I reinstalled XAMPP with admin privileges to try and fix another issue where the client wasn't able to connect it stopped working. I changed it to 'localhost', 'root','','dwellers'.

Comment: 1) You should use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) which incorporates all the elements you're using but is easier and more secure. 2) Your code is susceptible to SQL injection, despite the escaping that you're doing. You should refactor to used prepared queries.

Comment: I found the issue, which was server sided. I'd misspelled a table entry. This is my first time working with MySQL. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in the comments you really should be using `password_hash` -- saves re-inventing the wheel. Additionally, you should be using prepared statements to handle user input.

```
<?

$msg = "";

do{
    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
        break;
    }

    // Set database credentials
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "some_user";
    $db_pass = "a_password";
    $db_name = "dwellers";

    // Enable error reporting
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    // Connect to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    $name      = $_POST['username']  ?? NULL;
    $email     = $_POST['email']     ?? NULL;
    $password  = $_POST['password']  ?? NULL;
    $cPassword = $_POST['cPassword'] ?? NULL;
    $active    = 1;

    if ( !$name || !$email || !$password || !$cpassword ){
        $msg = "Error: Not all fields were completed <br><br>";
        break;
    }

    // Check if passwords are the same
    if ( $password != $cPassword ){
        $msg = "Error: Passwords are not the same <br><br>";
        break;
    }

    // You can change PASSWORD_DEFAULT and add options to set preferences
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // SQL query prep
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO user
            (username, password, email, active)
        VALUES
            (?, ?, ?, ?)
    ";

    // Prepare the query
    $query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    // Bind parameters to placeholders
    $query->bind_param("sssi", $name, $hash, $email, $active)

    // Execute the query
    $query->execute();

    $msg = "Success: You're registered <br><br>";
} while ( FALSE );
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MMORPG Registration File</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>MMORPG Account registration</h1>

<?=$msg?>

<form method="POST" action="register.php">
    <label>Username:</label><input name="username"><br>
    <label>Email:</label><input name="email"><br>
    <label>Password:</label><input name="password" type="password"><br>
   <label>Confirm Password:</label><input name="cPassword" type="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: whats with the do/while?

Comment: @LawrenceCheroneit saves having to nest if statements?